# Printing char array in C causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault

I did a lot of searching around for this, couldn't find any question with the same exact issue.

Here is my code:

```
void fun(char* name){
    printf("%s",name);
}

char name[6];
sscanf(input,"RECTANGLE_SEARCH(%6[A-Za-z0-9])",name)
printf("%s",name);
fun(name);
```

The name is grabbed from `scanf`, and it printed out fine at first. Then when `fun` is called, there is a segmentation fault when it tries to print out name. Why is this?

Comment: You should include the `scanf` line in your question.

Comment: The size of name (ie 6) seems pretty small.  What if you increase it t 100.

Comment: I included the scanf line. And 6 is the max character length for what I'm working with

Comment: What is `searchName`? Shouldn't that be `name`?

Comment: Sorry, I changed the code up some and forgot that ^

Answer (score 2):

After looking in my scrying-glass, I have it:

Your `scanf` did overflow the buffer (more than 6 byte including terminator read), with ill-effect slightly delayed due to circumstance:

Nobody else relied on or re-used the memory corrupted at first, thus the first `printf` seems to work.

Somewhere after the first and before the second call to `printf` the space you overwrote got re-used, so the string you read was no longer terminated before encountering not allocated pages.
Thus, a segmentation-fault at last.

Of course, your program was toast the moment it overflowed the buffer, not later when it finally crashed.
Morale: Never write to memory you have not dedicated for that.

Looking at your edit, the format `%6[A-Za-z0-9]` tries to read up to 6 characters exclusive the terminator, not inclusive!

Comment: I tried calling printf twice before the function call, it printed the name twice successfully then segfault

Comment: Thanks! I changed the 6 to a 5 and viola!

Comment: Glad to help. Just remember, if you violate the contract (invoke UB, e.g. by overflowing buffers), there is no guarantee when, whether or how you are caught, nor what will happen then. UB can be subtle or heavy-handed, obvious or without effect.

Comment: @GregBrinker It looks like `name` is allocated on the stack, which means that writing to 7th and later bytes will either corrupt the existing stack, causing nastiness to happen as soon as you try to call another function (`fun`), or if your compiler works the other way, allocating and using the new stack frame by calling `fun` will overwrite the dangling 7th+ bytes.

Comment: removal of string instruments is a possible effect of undefined behaviour

Comment: @MattMcNabb: As long as it leaves me the wind instruments.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're reading 6 characters, you have to declare `name` to be 7 characters, so there's room for the terminating null character:

```
char name[7];
```

Otherwise, you'll get a buffer overflow, and the consequences are undefined. Once you have undefined consequences, anything can happen, including 2 successful calls to `printf()` followed by a segfault when you call another function.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `name` is zero byte terminated? `scanf` can overflow your buffer depending on how you are calling it.

If that happens then `printf` will read beyond the end of the array resulting in undefined behavior and probably a segmentation fault.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: At the time that was the best answer that could be given without the specifics of the `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably walking off the end of the array with your printf statement. Printf uses the terminating null character '\0' to know where the end of the string is. Try allocating your array like this:

```
char name[6] = {'\0'};
```

This will allocate your array with every element initially set to the '\0' character, which means that as long as you don't overwrite the entire array with your scanf, printf will terminate before walking off the end.

Comment: `scanf` will 0-terminate the read string, always. Unless the format-specifier is `%c` for *any character*.