# Why is segmentation fault happening in this C program?

Tags: c, arrays, file, segmentation-fault

I made a simple C program to read data from a .txt file and print it on to the screen.

```
FILE *fp = fopen("words.txt", "r");

char buffer[3];

while (fscanf(fp, "%s", buffer) != EOF)
printf(" %s\n ", buffer);

printf("\n");
```

word.txt just has 123 written inside it. Now, the output I get when I run the program is

```
123
Segmentation fault
```

Why is that segmentation fault coming and what does it imply?

Comment: `char buffer[3];` --> `char buffer[4];`, `fscanf(fp, "%s", buffer)` --> `fscanf(fp, "%3s", buffer)`

Comment: You forgot the '\0' of the string, word.txt content will translate to "123\0" in your program. Change buffer[3] to buffer[4];

Comment: Change buffer[3] to buffer[256] and just stop bean-counting, (unless you are on some RAM-restricted embedded system).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing char array in C causes segmentation fault](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519497/printing-char-array-in-c-causes-segmentation-fault)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C `printf()`, `scanf()`, `fscanf()`, and actually most of the string functionality works with *null terminated string*.

> In computer programming, a null-terminated string is a character string stored as an array containing the characters and terminated with a null character (`'\0'`, called NUL in ASCII).

So when your input contains 3 characters, you must also reserve space for the null character.
In your example, the buffer should be at least of size 4.

To prevent user error, you could always limit the size of the input using:

```
char buffer[16]; // An array of 16 for example
scanf("%15s", buffer); // Must also reserve space for the null
```

Note that the `Segmentation fault` you are getting is **not** due to the `fscanf()` function trying to write `NULL` to the 4th character of the buffer.
This will only override some of the local variables on the stack.

The error is most likely due to writing `NULL` to the memory location where the pointer to the file is stored (`FILE *fp`), yielding `Segmentation fault` on the next iteration of the while, when we try to read from the file again.

To illustrate it, this is how your stack looks like:

```
| buffer[0] | buffer[1] | buffer[2] | fp | fp | fp | fp | ...
```

`fscanf()` tries to write `"123\0"` to the buffer, so it starts with the beginning of the buffer and put 1,2,3 in places 0,1,2 respectively. But the `NULL` characters placed exactly where part of `fp` is, thus corrupting the pointer.

Comment: I am always happy to hear criticism, so it will be great to know why the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

your string buffer needs to have space for the '\0' character that indicates the end of a string: a string "123" is actually ['1', '2', '3', '\0']. `fscanf` will automatically add the '\0'.

Answer (score 0):

Your specific problem is that [c-strings](/questions/tagged/c-strings) are **nul-terminateed** array of chars.

That in other words means that 3 chars string needs 4 bytes `char` buffer to be stored:

```
------------------
| 1 | 2 | 3 | \0 |
------------------
```

So

```
char buffer[3];
```

must be

```
char buffer[4];
```

BTW this is not a fully correct solution, because of you must declare your array large enough to contain the longest string can be retrieved in the file.

Answer (score 0):

it's because of the NULL character `\0` you string is not 3 character long but actually 4 char long. Your buffer is too small

just an advice, using fscanf is not the best solution i think

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  FILE *f = fopen("words.txt", "rb");
  fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
  long fsize = ftell(f);
  fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);  //same as rewind(f);                                  

  char *string = malloc(fsize + 1);
  fread(string, fsize, 1, f);
  fclose(f);

  string[fsize] = 0;
  printf("%s\n", string);
}
```

using fread is a better solution